# Solve the differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider
$\frac{dx}{dt} = Ax$ where $A$ is the matrix
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & -2 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Construct a real matrix $P$ such that the change of coordinates $x=Py$ transforms our real equation to

$\frac{dy}{dt}=By$ where $B$ is the matrix

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -\sqrt{2} \\
        0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

then solve explicity for $y$ and evaluate the solution in terms of our original $x=Py$

Solution

I have found $P$ as below

$$
       P =\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 & -1/\sqrt2 \\
        0 & 3 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 3/\sqrt2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

however I am stuck with the second part of solving explicitly for $y$ and evaluating the solution in terms of our original $x$ coordinates by $x=Py$

Comment: If $x=Py$, then $y=$?

Answer (score 2):

The first row of $B$ should read $(1,0,0)$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$ and $\pm\sqrt{2} i$. Consider three corresponding eigenvectors $f_1=(1,0,0)$, $f$, $\bar f$. Put $f_2:=(f+\bar f)/2$, $f_3:=(f-\bar f)/(2i)$. We now adopt  the $f_i$ as new (real!) basis vectors. Writing the $f_i$ into the columns of a matrix $P$ (not necessarily coinciding with your $P$) we get the transformation matrix from the given coordinates $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to new coordinates $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$. Our system now reads
$${dy\over dt}=By \tag{1}$$
with
$$B=P^{-1}A P=\left[\matrix{1&0&0\cr 0&0&-\sqrt{2}\cr 0&\sqrt{2}&0\cr}\right]\ .$$
Expanding $(1)$ in coordinates we have
$$\dot y_1=y_1,\quad \dot y_2=-\sqrt{2}y_3,\quad \dot y_3=\sqrt{2} y_2\ .$$
The interdependence between $y_2$ and $y_3$ mimicks the connection between $\cos$ and $\sin$. In short, 
$$\eqalign{t\mapsto y^{(1)}(t)&:=(e^t,0,0)^\top,\cr t\mapsto y^{(2)}(t)&:=(0,\cos(\sqrt{2} t),\sin(\sqrt{2} t))^\top,\cr t\mapsto y^{(3)}(t)&:=(0,\sin(\sqrt{2} t),-\cos(\sqrt{2} t))^\top\cr} $$
are three linearly independent solutions of $(1)$; therefore they form a basis of the solution space.

To obtain these three functions in terms of the old coordinates we have to use the transformation matrix $P$:
$$x^{(k)}(t)= P y^{(k)}(t)\qquad(1\leq k\leq 3)\ .$$

Comment: can you confirm the P calculated is correct? thanks

Comment: are the y values shown found using a rotation matrix?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
B^2=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&-2&0\\
0&0&-2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus,
$$
e^{Bt}=\begin{bmatrix}
e^t&0&0\\
0&\cos(t\sqrt2)&-\sin(t\sqrt2)\\
0&\sin(t\sqrt2)&\cos(t\sqrt2)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Next, apply $P$: $e^{At}=Pe^{Bt}P^{-1}$.